# How can I use the features embedding from wav2vec model?

Tags: neural-networks, transformers

I learned how to get the embedding features from wav2vec from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69266293/getting-embeddings-from-wav2vec2-models-in-huggingface) but I have some questions.

1. What is the difference between using those fixed embedding features
   in a downstream task and fine-tuning the model? I know that I can
   use the fixed embedding features with text(for example: BERT) but
   Does the same thing apply for audio data and wav2vec?
2. The resulting embeddings are long sequences of vectors(for example:
   the sequence length is 1676 for a 30 second audio file). What is the
   best way to shorten that sequence assuming that my data have audio
   files with different length?